# Perform a raycast using Chipmunk2D to detect collisions between two different types

Tags: c++, raycasting, chipmunk

So I have this example:

```cpp
#include <numbers>
#include <vector>
#include <chipmunk/chipmunk.h>

constexpr float SPRITE_SIZE{64};
constexpr double MAX_SEE_AHEAD{2 * SPRITE_SIZE};
constexpr int STEP_COUNT{4};
constexpr double OBSTACLE_AVOIDANCE_ANGLE{60 * (std::numbers::pi / 180)};

cpVect raycast(const cpVect &currentPosition, const cpVect &currentVelocity, cpSpace *space, const float angle = 0) {
  const auto rotated_velocity{cpvnormalize(cpvrotate(currentVelocity, cpvforangle(angle)))};
  cpShapeFilter wallFilter = cpShapeFilterNew(CP_NO_GROUP, 2, CP_ALL_CATEGORIES);
  for (int step = 1; step <= STEP_COUNT; step++) {
    const cpVect position{currentPosition + (rotated_velocity * step * (MAX_SEE_AHEAD / STEP_COUNT))};
    if (cpSpacePointQueryNearest(space, position, SPRITE_SIZE / 2, wallFilter, nullptr)) {
      return position;
    }
  }
  return {-1, -1};
}

inline cpVect convertPos(const int x, const int y) {
  return {static_cast<float>(x) * SPRITE_SIZE + SPRITE_SIZE / 2, static_cast<float>(y) * SPRITE_SIZE + SPRITE_SIZE / 2};
}

int main() {
  // Create the space
  cpSpace *space{cpSpaceNew()};

  // Create the player
  const std::vector vertices{convertPos(1, 2), convertPos(2, 2), convertPos(1, 3), convertPos(2, 3)};
  cpBody *playerBody{cpBodyNewKinematic()};
  cpShape *playerShape{cpPolyShapeNew(playerBody, 4, vertices.data(), cpTransformIdentity, 0.0)};
  cpSpaceAddBody(space, playerBody);
  cpShapeSetBody(playerShape, playerBody);
  cpSpaceAddShape(space, playerShape);
  cpBodySetPosition(playerBody, {128, 192});
  cpBodySetVelocity(playerBody, {0, 100});
  cpShapeSetCollisionType(playerShape, 1);
  cpShapeSetFilter(playerShape, cpShapeFilterNew(CP_NO_GROUP, 1, 2));

  // Add a wall to the space
  cpBody *wallBody{cpBodyNewStatic()};
  cpShape *wallShape{cpBoxShapeNew(wallBody, SPRITE_SIZE, SPRITE_SIZE, 0.0)};
  cpSpaceAddBody(space, wallBody);
  cpShapeSetBody(wallShape, wallBody);
  cpSpaceAddShape(space, wallShape);
  cpBodySetPosition(wallBody, {128, 320});
  cpShapeSetCollisionType(wallShape, 2);
  cpShapeSetFilter(wallShape, cpShapeFilterNew(CP_NO_GROUP, 2, CP_ALL_CATEGORIES));

  // Do the raycast using cpSpacePointQueryNearest
  const cpVect currentPosition{cpBodyGetPosition(playerBody)};
  const cpVect currentVelocity{cpBodyGetVelocityAtWorldPoint(playerBody, cpvzero)};
  const cpVect forward_ray{raycast(currentPosition, currentVelocity, space)};
  const cpVect left_ray{raycast(currentPosition, currentVelocity, space, OBSTACLE_AVOIDANCE_ANGLE)};
  const cpVect right_ray{raycast(currentPosition, currentVelocity, space, -OBSTACLE_AVOIDANCE_ANGLE)};

  return 0;
}
```

However, I don't think the filters are setup correctly since the left, forward, and right rays all return the first step position (which is within the player's bbox). What should happen is the left and right rays return `cpVect(-1, -1)` while the forward ray returns `cpVect(128, 288)` (the first point to intersect the wall's bbox.